# Push Notification not working with push notification time

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, pyfcm

When I am using push notification in python then I am not able to sent push notification time as per required

Example : 1m or 60m etc

I am using https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM this in application.

Please give me example how to send push notification time as per required

```
registration_id = request.POST['registration_id']
message_title = request.POST['message_title']
message_body = request.POST['message_body']
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
```

Where we need to sent push notification type for this application When I am setting time then getting so many problems and example not exit in whole example.

Full Example:

```
def index(request):
    if (request.POST['type'] == 'android'):
        push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="abc.pem")
        registration_id = request.POST['registration_id']
        message_title = request.POST['message_title']
        message_body = request.POST['message_body']
        result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
        print result
        return HttpResponse("Hello Testing, world. You're at the tesing index.")
    else:
        apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='abc.pem', enhanced=True)
        token_hex = request.POST['registration_id']
        messageTitle = request.POST['message_title']
        dict = {'title': request.POST['message_title'], 'body': request.POST['message_body']}
        payload = Payload(alert=dict, sound="default", badge=1)
        apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
        frame = Frame()
        identifier = 1
        expiry = time.time()+3600
        priority = 10
        frame.add_item(request.POST['registration_id'], payload, identifier, expiry, priority)
        return HttpResponse("Hello Testing, world. You're at the tesing index second")
```

Comment: how do you setting time ??

Comment: I am using same code as per example please provide me example how can I set time for sending push notification

Comment: @somil please check now whole example Now I am using these code but where we need to set time as per required elements not exist in example

Comment: Please check now my full example

Comment: @somil When I am using push notifications then in push notification setting we are not able to pass parameters for send push notification to other user

Comment: I am using push notification will send to other user not current user but we need push  notification send to other user by time limit mean 60m or 30m etc

Comment: this is our post request as per setting So please provide m solution how We set time for push notification